# How to exit a function with infinite loop of channel

Tags: go

I have this function that listens to RabbitMQ to consume a message.
And at some point, I want to stop listening and close the channel and quit the function.

```
func WaitForConfirm(expectedLen int){
    count := 0
    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            count++
            if count == expectedLen {
                // HERE I WANT TO EXIT THE FUNCTION COMPLETELY
            }
        }
    }()

    <-forever
}
```

Oh, btw, I call this function like this:

```
go WaitForConfirm(2)
```

So, how can I stop the infinite loop and exit the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no infinite loop in your code and just chan is blocking your code.

You should send value to chan to release execution.

Here Example: https://go.dev/play/p/ujJjwBBsiP0

Comment: `close(forever)` is a safer option than sending to the channel, as it cannot block and all receivers on the channel will get the signal

Comment: Yeap, thats a good point